# Как отследить событие ajax на странице, чтобы по нему запустить скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице происходят ajax запросы, мне нужно после каждого ajax запроса запускать скрипт js, как это сделать?

Comment: В общем случае никак

Comment: Скрипт - функция? Если да, то можно ее вызывать в success функции ajax.

Comment: @Kirzzz да, можно в success или в .done, меня интересует событие в браузере, так как  не хочу править код шаблона, иначе обновления шаблона затрут все мои изменения

Comment: Нет такого события в браузере. В jQuery есть [глобальные события](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), но они срабатывают только для запросов сделанных через jQuery же. Если запрос был сделан напр-р через `XMLHttpRequest` или `fetch`, его никак не отследить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в jQuery Есть глобальные обработчики событий, такие как ajaxSuccess - в данном случае этот обработчик будет срабатывать после каждого удачного запроса.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  //ваш код
});
```

Comment: повезло, что ajax через jquery срабатывает) спасибо) странно что таких глобальных событий нет  для javascript

Answer (score 1):

После выполнения запроса используйте .done .fail вот их и используйте

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
  }).done((response) => {
    //console.log(response);
    document.querySelector('#result').prepend(JSON.stringify(response, null, '   '));
  }).fail((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id='result'></pre>
```